# Nodes defined recursively

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code is straightforward (I have left blank lines to distinguish 5 sections):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (12,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,5);
  \coordinate (f0) at ($(B)!(C)!(A)$);

  \coordinate (f1) at ($(C)!(f0)!(A)$);
  \coordinate (f2) at ($(B)!(f1)!(A)$);
  \coordinate (f3) at ($(C)!(f2)!(A)$);
  \coordinate (f4) at ($(B)!(f3)!(A)$);
  \coordinate (f5) at ($(C)!(f4)!(A)$);
  \coordinate (f6) at ($(B)!(f5)!(A)$);

  \draw (B) -- (A) -- (C)
        node [midway,above] {$\mathbf b$} --
        node [midway, left] {$\mathbf a$}    cycle;

  \filldraw[fill=blue!5!white, draw=black]
    (C) -- (f0) node [midway,left] {$h_0$} --
           (f1) node [midway,above,left] {$a_0$} --
           (f2) node [midway,left] {$h_1$} --
           (f3) node [midway,above,left] {$a_1$} --
           (f4) node [midway,left] {$h_2$} --
           (f5) node [midway,above,left] {$a_2$};

  \draw
      (B) --
      (f0) node [midway,below] {$c_0$} --
      (f2) node [midway,below] {$c_1$} --
      (f4) node [midway,below] {$c_2$} --
      (f6) node [midway,below] {$c_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

1. Defines the coordinates of a right triangle, and the **base point** of the construction.
2. Defines each new coordinate as the foot of a height to either segment CA or BA **from a previously computed coordinate**, starting from the base point.
3. Draw the triangle.
4. Draw the heights toward BA **and label them**.
5. Draw the heights toward CA.

> My question is what is the syntax to automate this process, so that I can do the same, not just 3 steps in, but 5, 10, or variably more steps?

Comment: you can define a new command (`\newcommand` or `\def`) cho that task

Answer (score 6):

With `\foreach`, only two paths to which the points are projected and a start point are needed.

In your case, `path 1` is `BA`, `path 2` is `CA`, `start` point is `C`. From start, `C` is projected to `path 1`, and then the perpendicular is projected to `path 2`, and new perpendicular is projected to `path 1` and so on...
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\perpset#1{\pgfqkeys{/perpendicular}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\perpset{
  /perpendicular/.search also=/tikz,
  path 1/.code args={from (#1) to (#2)}{
    \def\perp@from@a{#1}
    \def\perp@to@a{#2}
  },
  path 2/.code args={from (#1) to (#2)}{
    \def\perp@from@b{#1}
    \def\perp@to@b{#2}
  },
  start/.code args={(#1)}{\def\perp@start{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\perpdraw}[2][1]{
  \begin{scope}[/perpendicular/.cd,#2]
  \coordinate (perp@start-0) at (\perp@start);
  \foreach \x [count=\i from 0] in {1, ..., #1} {
    \draw[fill=blue!5] (perp@start-\i)
    -- node[left, teal] {$h_\i$} ($(\perp@from@a)!(perp@start-\i)!(\perp@to@a)$) coordinate (perp@end-\i)
    -- node[left, red] {$a_\i$} ($(\perp@from@b)!(perp@end-\i)!(\perp@to@b)$) coordinate (perp@start-\x);
  }
  \end{scope}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A) at (12,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (3,5);
  \draw (B) -- (A) -- (C)
        node [midway,above] {$\mathbf b$} --
        node [midway, left] {$\mathbf a$}    cycle;
  \perpdraw[4]{
    path 1=from (B) to (A),
    path 2=from (C) to (A),
    start=(C),
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

One `\foreach` loop is enough to draw. The coordinates `(Ai)`, `(Bi)`, `(Ci)`are recusively defined.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[join=round]
\path
(0,0) coordinate (B0)
(12,0) coordinate (A0)
(2,6) coordinate (C0)
;
\draw (B0)--(A0)--(C0)
node[midway,above]{$\mathbf b$} --
node[midway,left]{$\mathbf a$}  cycle;

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(\i-1)} 
\path
($(A\j)!(C\j)!(B\j)$) coordinate (B\i)
($(A\j)!(B\i)!(C\j)$) coordinate (C\i)
(A\j) coordinate (A\i);
\fill[brown!30] (C\j)--(B\i)--(C\i)--cycle;
\draw[blue] (B\i)--(B\j) node[midway,below] {$c_{\j}$};
\draw[red] (C\j)--(B\i) node[pos=.7,left]{$h_{\j}$};
\draw[violet] (B\i)--(C\i) node[pos=.7,above left]{$a_{\j}$};
}
\draw (A0)--(C0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```